# Цикл While и разовый вывод сообщения PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Есть такой цикл.

```
        while($resultat = $q->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)){
    if ($checkit != $resultat['name'])
    {   

        $i++;
        continue; //Если убрать, то выводит несколько-подряд.
        //Где то тут должно вывести сообщение, что такого кода не существует;
    }
    if ($checkit == $resultat['name']){

      if ($counter2 > 0 && $active != false){
        mysqli_query($bds,"UPDATE bonus SET counter=counter-1 WHERE name='$checkit'");
        mysqli_query($bds,"UPDATE users SET last_code=CONCAT(last_code, '".$data['bonuscode'].",') WHERE id='$u->id'");
        mysqli_query($bds,"UPDATE users SET money=money+'$action2' WHERE id='$u->id'");
         echo "Код успешно активирован. На ваш счет начислено ".$action2." игровой валюты. Обновите страницу, или нажмите на кнопку ниже.";
        }else{
            echo "Код недействителен";
        }

    }


    }
```

Задача вот в чем..нужно в первом условии, где НЕ РАВНО выводить 1 единственный раз сообщение о том, что такого кода не существует. Если убрать CONTINUE, то сообщение выведется ровно столько раз, сколько будет сравниваться записей..Как можно исправить ?
P.S Break не подходит.

Answer (score 0):

по коду видно, что он выводит сообщений столько раз сколько ошибок. Добавте переменную $message и при выводе проверяйте есть ли там что-то. Если есть то больше не выводите сообщение

```php
$message = false;
while($resultat = $q->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)){
    if ($checkit != $resultat['name'] && $message === false)
    {   
        $i++;
        $message = "Ошибка";
        echo($message);
        continue; //Если убрать, то выводит несколько-подряд.
        //Тут не выведиться потому что стоит continue
    }
    if ($checkit == $resultat['name']){

      if ($counter2 > 0 && $active != false){
        mysqli_query($bds,"UPDATE bonus SET counter=counter-1 WHERE name='$checkit'");
        mysqli_query($bds,"UPDATE users SET last_code=CONCAT(last_code, '".$data['bonuscode'].",') WHERE id='$u->id'");
        mysqli_query($bds,"UPDATE users SET money=money+'$action2' WHERE id='$u->id'");
         echo "Код успешно активирован. На ваш счет начислено ".$action2." игровой валюты. Обновите страницу, или нажмите на кнопку ниже.";
        }else{
            echo "Код недействителен";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Сообщение об ошибке все равно выведется хотя бы 1 раз..т.е когда найдется существующий код, сначала вылезет "Ошибка" и затем слитно "Код успешно...."

Comment: Тогда сделайте 2 переменные. $errormassage  и $success message. После обработки выводить их как вам нужно